# Кириллица и команда groff на freeBSD

Tags: кодировка, freebsd

Здравствуйте.

Предыстория такая. Решил научиться пользоваться groff, но столкнулся с проблемой: не отображаются некоторые кирилические символы (сначала вообще ничего не хотело отображаться, но я [прочитал этот пост](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2011-08/msg00037.html) и сделал всё как там написано).

**Проблема**
Периодически (например, когда на ввод подаётся предложение "адрес источника адрес назначения") не хочет отображаться буква "к".
Платформа, под которой эксперементирую FreeBSD (тестил на Linux, отображаются все символы).
Создаю документ таким образом (создаётся без сообщений об ошибках).

```
cat mydoc | preconv -e koi8-r | groff -Tps -mru > something.ps
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы.
Если нужна какая-то дополнительная информация, то с радостью вам предоставлю.